# Draw Pie HighCharts from json value,

Tags: java, jquery, json, highcharts

Hi i am trtying to draw a Pie highchart using json value  i have json value in following format.

```
Data=  {"count":[62,58,10,6],"categoires":["a1","a2","a3","a4"]}
```

Hi have code of Highchart like this

```
            $('#2Chieldrightdiv').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    type: 'pie'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                        },
                        showInLegend: true
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Brands',
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: [{
                        name: cat,
                        y: Count
                    }]
                }]
            });

        }
```

But chart is not drawing  i am new in Highchart so please help me  to sort out this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Try removing any and all but the most necessary options to make the chart  after that add the various options you need and see when it stops drawing itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of that is you refer to array of points in single point. As a result you have something like:

```
series: [{
                name: 'Brands',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [{
                    name: ["a1","a2","a3","a4"],
                    y: [62,58,10,6]
                }]
            }]
```

but you should have:

```
data: [{
                        name: "a1",
                        y: 62
       },{
                        name: "a2",
                        y: 58
       },{
                        name: "a3",
                        y: 10
       },{
                        name: "a4",
                        y: 6
       }]
```